# Dual boot install

Tags: system-installation

I have a 64-bit Win7 laptop and I would like to try Ubuntu with dual-boot option. Can I install Ubuntu on a sd or flash drive and have everything related to Ubuntu including programs, apps, etc on that drive instead of on my harddrive and still have dual-boot?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Yes you can have a partually functional portable linux install on an sd card or usb drive. No that install won't be like a regular dual boot due to 3 main reasons.

1. SD cards and all usb's except 3.0 are slower than any sata interface so the os will run slower
2. Due to the fact that it's installed on an SD card you cannot have the regular GRUB bootloader just give you a choice of what to boot in , instead you will have to select in bios to boot from usb or sd card.
3. When you install linux on an SD card or USB you cannot use the actual installer because as far as i know you can't just boot your pc from ubuntu cd with a usb plugged in and expect to see the usb in the installer(not sure for the latest versions could actually be possible) , you will have to use unetbootin or similar which will make a live cd not an actual install  and will limit the amount of changes you can do to this by making a live cache and this live cache will limit the changes you do eg. installing stuff because the purpose of a live cd is to give you a short demonstration of the os and a few features to play with  and let you install the os , not be the os.

Apart from that it will work

Answer (score 0):

Well running Ubuntu on a SD card is very slow. You won't get anywhere near SSD performance.  Its due to the read/write speed limitations of SD cards.  Now installing on a USB flash drive would give better, performance.

Make sure that you do it with 8GB flash drive.  4GB for `/`,4GB for /home and SWAP. You can create partitions during installation.  Keep in mind that USB 2.0 is some what slow, you should consider using a USB 3.0 fast flash drive if your PC has USB 3.0 capability.

Now for installing programs on the flash drive, depending on what, and how many apps you need, maybe you should consider a larger USB.

You may want to look at [Live Usb Pendrive Persistent](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent)